# django filters - dictionary of filters alongside Q filtering

Tags: django, django-views

I have a django query which is built from URL get paramaters. These are constructed by a dictionary named 'filters':

```
filters['published_date__year'] = year
filters['published_date__week'] = week
filters['source__slug'] = source

queryset = Headline.objects.filter(**filters)
```

What I'm also wanting to do is apply multiple AND filters on a field name 'tag'.

```
filter1 = Q(tags__slug=windows)
filter2 = Q(tags__slug=microsoft)
```

Where the results would be filtered to only show headlines that have windows AND microsoft.

Is it possible to apply both these Q filters, alongside the standard ones?

Cheers

Comment: I think it is possible. Take a look at complex queries doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in an old project of mine where I filtered the queryset of a user's input for two attributes containing the user's input. I think what you want to use is something along the lines of this

```
results = Headline.objects.filter((Q(tags__slug=windows)) | Q(tags__slug=microsoft)))
```

where the `|` is used to take the union of two querysets. Hopefully this is helps with your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the use of  filtering using Q, the issue is using them at the same time as the regular filters (in a dict like I have). Ideally I could apply these filters at the same time, in the same way..just not sure if it possible or not.